# Are the RSS feeds updating properly?

Tags: bug, feed

I set up Filtered Questions RSS feeds on stackexchange.com. I have grouped the sites that I'm interested in into categories - one includes Stack Overflow, Software Engineering, SQA & Testing, Computer Science, DevOps, and others (about a dozen sites in total). Today, I got home from work and started browsing the feed. There were about 200 questions that showed up in Feedly. But I noticed that only 2 were from Software Engineering.

I know for a fact that between the time I left for work and now, more than 2 new questions were posted on Software Engineering. This means it's highly likely that I'm missing other questions in other groups as well.

I'm unsure if this is on Feedly's end or Stack Exchange's end, but if I have an RSS feed of newest questions (All Questions) on a set of sites, at the end of the day, I should have all of the questions in my feed.

Here is an example of a configuration that I do not believe is showing me all questions:

[image: Stack Exchange RSS Feed Configuration]

Comment: You may wish to screenshot your filter so we have an idea on what you did (and if it's possible or not as a root cause)

Comment: @Tensibai Done - this is one that appears to not be showing all questions posted.

Comment: Really more clear as a kind of bug now, with "all questions filter" there's nothing likely to be drop because of tag mismatch for exemple ;)