# With the improvements to tag watching, tag notifications, and custom question lists, is any attention being paid to cross-site discovery?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, site-recommendation, tag-watching

With the new changes to [tag watching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312180/favorite-tags-is-now-tag-watching) with some more changes around notifications coming and [new controls to build custom question lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312781/custom-question-lists-finding-questions-you-can-answer) also coming, are there any plans for fixing instances where people have expertise that spans multiple sites?

For example, questions that I can answer based on my education and professional experience span at least 5 sites - Stack Overflow, Software Engineering, Software Quality Assurance & Testing, Project Management, and The Workplace. There are even some other sites that have some overlap - Open Source, Law, DevOps, and a few others. Each of these sites have tags for and questions in those tags that my expertise allows me to answer, some with more than others.

Honestly, keeping track of so many sites is a pain for someone who is an expert on a given topic or set of topics and just wants to find questions to answer and get notified of new questions in their area of expertise. These new tools should help a lot on a single site. But it doesn't address when someone's expertise crosses multiple sites.

The RSS feeds are somewhat OK, but I think there are issues with them. [I posted a possible bug since it looks like my RSS feeds are not including all questions posted to all sites in the feed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310015/572). Having something on the SE platform seems like it would be better than trying to rely on RSS readers to collate the results and not drop anything. It would also keep people on the platform and be able to react and adapt as new sites are added, without needing to manually update RSS feeds.

Comment: I like the idea, but it sounds cumbersome to allow tag filtering on sites which don't have a specific tag in the list. I'm unsure SE needs to add this complexity in the core without data about how much person this may concern, but this question is likely to showcase the overall community appeal about that.

Comment: @Tensibai It could potentially replace the RSS feeds - you specify the site and either "all questions" or specific tags on that site. Different sites may use tags differently, so you don't want to equate a tag on Site A with a tag on Site B just by tag name. It would be nice to also include suggested tags for each site (so if you follow tag X and Y on Site A, it may suggest tag Z on site A as well). But that's just one possible implementation.

Comment: I got that, what I mean is how much people are likely to use it vs a feed aggregation or multiple tabs on their workstation. This kind of implementation is likely to be costly in time and complexity, it has to be balanced by a real need (at least, because a bunch of feature requests have been declined despite large community support)

Comment: @Tensibai A Meta post isn't useful for that - there's not enough participation here from all users across all sites in the network. You'd have to collect data through other means to determine if this is viable. I do know that this is incredibly painful for me, and has been since the first SE sites other than SO were opened.

Comment: I've no problem with it, I can see it can be useful, and I understand your pain. My main concern is balancing more complex code with its use, it may worth a Team DAG survey across sites indeed if you don't have other anecdotal data than your own (no offense intended, but it worth knowing if you're alone, 3, or far more wishing this, I'm confident votes and answers here will bring this case of 'early poll')